# Calculate statistics (estimate, confidence intervals, standard error) for a contrast matrix in ANOVA/ANCOVA/GLM

Tags: multiple-regression, confidence-interval, inference, f-statistic

I am interested in calculating the relevant statistics for a contrast *matrix* in an ANOVA/ANCOVA/GLM setting. Kutner et al. call this the "matrix formulation" of the "general linear test". They give as an example in Chapter 23.5 (of the 5th ed.):
$$C = \left [ \begin{array}{cccccc} 
2/3 & -2/3 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 0 \\
2/3 & 0 & -2/3 & 1/3 & 0 & -1/3 \end{array} \right ]$$

As a simpler example (and closer to what I am working with in my research), in a 3x3 ANOVA without interactions, the "main effect of A" contrast would be (assuming intercept for the first column, and 2 columns each for effects A and B):$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right]$$This formulation is very common in neuroimaging (see e.g., [ANOVAs and SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/publications/rik_anova.pdf) and [Contrasts and Classical Inference](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/mbi/contrasts.pdf). I have been successful in calculating these values for t-contrasts (i.e., single row or column, depending on how you look at it), with the contrast of parameter estimates simply equaling $C^T \hat{\beta}$ and the CI's equaling $C^T \hat{\beta} \pm t_{\alpha/2,df}$.

I have been able to calculate the F-statistic as $$F_{rk(C),n-p} = \frac{(C\beta)^T (C (X^T X)^{-1} C^T)^{-1} C\beta) / rk(C)}{\epsilon^T \epsilon / (n - p)}$$ and then calculate the p-value. Then if this contrast is significant, I would do post-hoc tests to compare individual treatment means.

However, I can't find out how to calculate the effect size estimate (in the above example I would get 2 values, 1 for each row of the contrast matrix), std. error, or confidence intervals for the estimates; nor am I sure if these values are necessary/useful for inference in this situation.

1. Ideally I'm looking for a solution that would also work for ANCOVA (with $\ge 1$ quantitative predictor), and really *General Linear Models* in general (pun not intended).

   a. Is this even necessary if I have *planned comparisons*; e.g., if I am only interested in testing whether $\mu_{11} - \mu_{21} = 0$ and I don't care about the other treatment levels.

Comment: This looks like an interesting post.  But if the only question is R implementation and the problem that occurs pressing Enter in the edit box then it is off topic for CV.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am not specifically interested in the R implementation (I would be happy to code it up myself). I am unsure of the actual equations. If it helps, I have access to several relevant textbooks (Christensen, Plane Answer...; Winer, Statistical Principles...; Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, & Li; etc.). I just can't find the relevant information.

Comment: Maybe then Stack Overflow would be better for your purposes. Coding issues are off topic here.

Comment: It's true that I am *ultimately* interested in coding up a solution, however I am not asking for code clarification or solutions here. I am looking to find out whether it is sensible to calculate these quantities, and how to do so (the equations would be enough, I think). If I should edit the post to make it clear that I am not specifically asking for programming/coding help, I will do so.

Comment: I think that might help a lot. It is not clear exactly what you want.  No one has voted to close the post yet.